# BroadcastReceiver receives more Intents than sent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-activity, android-service

I have next problem:

I create a custom BroadcastReceiver and register it in main activity onCreate handler:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
  private static final LogReceiver logReceiver = new LogReceiver();

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(logReceiver, new IntentFilter(LogReceiver.ACTION_LOG));
  }
...
}
```

BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class LogReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.i("intent", "intent <-");
  }
}
```

Then I send multiple Intents from a local service using next code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LogReceiver.ACTION_LOG).putExtra("log", logString);
localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
Log.i("intent", "intent ->");
```

The log looks very strange for me:

- intent ->
- intent <-
- intent ->
- intent <-
- intent <-
- intent ->
- intent <-
- intent <-
- intent <-
- ...

The 1st time LogReceiver receives only one Intent and this is correct but each next time it receives more equal Intents than sent.

I can switch from Intent approach in my project but just interesting why this happens?

Comment: you probably register a whole bunch of receivers (one each time you enter your app, unless you unregister them)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Indeed you are right. OnCreate is called multiple times - just checked this using a debugger. It seems that I have to review Activity Lifecycle article :)

Comment: Move your registering code to onResume and unregister in onPause.

Answer (score 0):

You should deregister the receiver in the onDestroy of the Activity.
Additionally you should check if this receiver really has to be static.

If you need the receiver throughout the application it should be saved in a separate singleton class or in a custom Application class instead of one Activity.

You could then register the receiver in the first started Activity. But you should make sure it is registered only once for example by storing a `boolean registered` into the receiver that is checked before registering at the LocalBroadcastManager.